# Invariant subspace of a diagonalizable operator

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let dim$V$ be finite. Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be a diagonalizable operator and $W\subseteq V$ such that $T(W)\subseteq W$. Then can we write $W$ as sum of ($1$-dimensional)  eigenspaces of $T$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T$ is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial $m$ has distinct roots in the underlying field.

Clearly $m(T) = 0$ implies $m(T|_{W}) = 0$. Therefore the minimal polynomial $n$ of $T|_{W}$ divides $m$, so that $n$ has also distinct roots, and therefore $T|_{W}$ is diagonalizable.

Now a ($1$-dimensional) eigenspace for $T|_{W}$ is also an eigenspace for $T$.